# Python decorator accessing the wrong function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

#### **My Understanding:**

Based on what I understand about decorator, the following code

```
def myDecorator(func):
   ...

@myDecorator
def myFunc()
```

is equivalent to

```
myFunc = myDecorator(myFunc)
```

#### **My Experiment**

So I'm playing around with this concept with the following code

```
def myDecorator(func):
        func()

@myDecorator
def myFunc():
    print("MyFunc is run")

@myDecorator
def myFunc2():
    print("MyFunc2 is run")

myFunc
```

The output is

```
MyFunc is run
MyFunc2 is run
```

#### **My Question**

What happen? Why the line `MyFunc2 is run` is printed? Aren't `myFunc` is equivalent to `myFunc = myDecorator(myFunc)`? If this is the case why `myFunc2` statement is run?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Functions are objects too, you passed `MyFunc2()` to the decorator function, which receives it as `func`. You then call `func()`.

Comment: You're last line with `myFunc` doesn't run the function. You're missing the parens.

Comment: @Matthias In this context it doesn't need the parens because myDecorator has invoke the function

Comment: That was what I was trying to explain. The line `myFunc` doesn't lead to any action, so the call that leads to the printing is done at another place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Shouldn't myFunc2 (I just edited the code from MyFunc2 to myFunc2, typo) only be triggered when I add another line `myFunc2`? Why is it called when I'm only issuing the statement `myFunc`?

Comment: @caramel1995: no, `def functionname(): ...` is executed immediately, including the decorator. The statement `myFunc` is *not doing anything*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Understood :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a function object to the `myDecorator()` function. That function receives the function object as the `func` parameter. You then *call* that function with `func()`.

You are right that `@myDecorator` on a function object causes that decorator to be called, with the function object being passed in. But you seem to be confused about *when that happens*. It happens the moment Python executes the `def` statement:

```
>>> def myDecorator(func):
...     func()
...
>>> @myDecorator
... def foo():
...     print('The foo() function is called')
...
The foo() function is called
```

Note that because `myDecorator()` has no `return` statement, `foo` is now bound to `None`:

```
>>> foo is None
True
```

Your last line, `myFunc`, does nothing more than just reference the `None` object. You didn't call it, so *that* expression does not cause anything to be printed. You *can't* call it, because `None` is not callable.

Comment: I got what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completness - a "generic" correct decorator returns a new function object, taht then replaces the original function in the scope it was declared:

```
def myDecorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """Calls original function with whatever parameters 
        and returns its return value.
        """
        print("Running decorator code")
        return func(*ars, **kwargs)
    # Returns the newly created 'wrapper' function
    # that will replace the original "func"
    return wrapper

@myDecorator
def myFunc():
    print("MyFunc is run")

@myDecorator
def myFunc2():
    print("MyFunc2 is run")

myFunc()
```